# Maximise Range Vs Pitching Down while flying a Glider in a Downward Air Mass

Tags: general-aviation, flight-dynamics, glider, glide-ratio

While flying a **glider**, if I encounter a downward moving air mass (i.e. sink) while on final, should I fly to maximise range (best lift to drag ratio) or should I pitch downward in order to exit the sinking air mass as quickly as possible, so that I do not lose too much altitude? A technical explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_to_fly

Comment: Simple trigonometry will answer your question.  You have to add the down draft velocity to your sink rate.  A higher glide speed has a higher sink rate than Vbg, but gets you out of the downdraft faster.

Comment: Unless you are an advanced pilot you should never be having to think about this question in flight.